# why is my code not writing to a new text file

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, text

Was looking for ideas as to why my code is not writing to a new text file. There are no errors to give me a clue.

```
def writeFile (filename, text):
file = open(greenBottle.txt, 'w')
file.write(text)
file.close()

    def main (text):

        big_nums = ['no','One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight','Nine','Ten']
        text_one = (' green bottles \nHanging on the wall\n')
        small_nums = [' no',' one',' two',' three',' four',' five',' six',' seven',' eight',' nine',' ten']
        text_two = ('And if one green bottle \nShould accidentally fall\nThere\'ll be')
        text_three = (' green bottles \nHanging on the wall\n \n')
        result=[]
        text=new_string
        new_string=''

        for i in range(10, 0, -1):
            result.append(big_nums[i] + str( text_one))
            result.append(big_nums[i] + str( text_one))
            result.append(text_two + small_nums[i-1] + text_three)
            return result('')
            print(''.join(main(text)))

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        writeFile('greenBottle.txt',text)


    main(text)
```

Comment: What OS ? maybe you don't have write permission to that folder ?

Comment: Win 7 and i am admin so have all permissions

Comment: This can't be the code you're running if you get no errors. This has many of them, e.g. text = new_string before declaring new_string, return result('') when result is a list (so not callable), text isn't defined when you call writeFile('greenBottle.txt',text) ... Show us your exact code.

Comment: miles82 This is the way i have it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned these lines are buggy and should be removed plus you cannot `return` from a for loop but only from a function:

```
return result('')
print(''.join(main(text)))
```

and this line is repeated:

```
result.append(big_nums[i] + str( text_one))
```

After I rewrote your code:

```
def writeFile (filename, text):
    with open(filename,'w') as file:
        for line in text:
            file.write(line)

def main():
    result=[]
    big_nums = ['no','One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight','Nine','Ten']
    text_one = (' green bottles \nHanging on the wall\n')
    small_nums = [' no',' one',' two',' three',' four',' five',' six',' seven',' eight',' nine',' ten']
    text_two = ('And if one green bottle \nShould accidentally fall\nThere\'ll be')
    text_three = (' green bottles \nHanging on the wall\n \n')
    new_string=''
    text = new_string

    for i in range(0,10):
        result.append(big_nums[i] + str( text_one))
        #result.append(big_nums[i] + str( text_one))
        result.append(text_two + small_nums[i-1] + text_three)
        #return result('')
        #print(''.join(main(text)))

    writeFile('greenBottle.txt',result)

main()
```

The Output:

```
no green bottles 
Hanging on the wall
And if one green bottle 
Should accidentally fall
There'll be ten green bottles 
Hanging on the wall

One green bottles 
Hanging on the wall
And if one green bottle 
Should accidentally fall
There'll be no green bottles 
Hanging on the wall

Two green bottles 
Hanging on the wall
And if one green bottle 
Should accidentally fall
There'll be one green bottles 
Hanging on the wall

Three green bottles 
Hanging on the wall
And if one green bottle 
Should accidentally fall
There'll be two green bottles 
Hanging on the wall

Four green bottles 
Hanging on the wall
And if one green bottle 
Should accidentally fall
There'll be three green bottles 
Hanging on the wall

Five green bottles 
Hanging on the wall
And if one green bottle 
Should accidentally fall
There'll be four green bottles 
Hanging on the wall

Six green bottles 
Hanging on the wall
And if one green bottle 
Should accidentally fall
There'll be five green bottles 
Hanging on the wall

Seven green bottles 
Hanging on the wall
And if one green bottle 
Should accidentally fall
There'll be six green bottles 
Hanging on the wall

Eight green bottles 
Hanging on the wall
And if one green bottle 
Should accidentally fall
There'll be seven green bottles 
Hanging on the wall

Nine green bottles 
Hanging on the wall
And if one green bottle 
Should accidentally fall
There'll be eight green bottles 
Hanging on the wall
```

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/2425215/k-dawg Thank you kind sir. Did not know you cannot return from a for loop but only from a function. but as i said i'm only a beginner so thanks for your knowledge

Comment: His `for` loop is inside a function, so of course he can return from it.